# $ionicPlatform.ready() not firing

Tags: ionic-framework

Recently I started working with ionic and I'm stuck in a weird bug that I can't find any solution, I have searching over the web and there isn't many solutions.
The problem is that the app works fine testing on pc and then when using it on an android device (not tested on ios) some code just dont fire.

Here is what I have:
(index.html)

```
<!-- compiled css output -->
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.js"> </script>
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-service-core/ionic-core.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

(app.js)

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

        var push = new Ionic.Push({
     "debug": true
    });

      push.register(function(token) {
      console.log("My Device token:",token.token);
      push.saveToken(token);  // persist the token in the Ionic Platform
      window.localStorage.setItem("idToken", token.token);

    });

        // Check for network connection 
        if (window.Connection) {
            if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
                $ionicPopup.confirm({
                        title: 'No Internet Connection',
                        content: 'Sorry, no Internet connectivity detected. Please reconnect and try again.'
                    })
                    .then(function (result) {
                        if (!result) {
                            ionic.Platform.exitApp();
                        }
                    });
            }
        }

        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

One of the errors that I get in android when I use the emulator is this:

```
Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/cordova_plugins.js
```

But in my path:

```
C:\myApp\platforms\android\assets\www
```

There is cordova_plugins.js

Is there something that I'm missing out?
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Put `debugger;` or `alert()` after `$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {` I think problem is not in `$ionicPlatform.ready()` function.

Comment: already tried... it works on pc but when I run it on a device (Android) throught an emulator or even a real one, it just don't fire the event

Comment: add this line `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` at top of all scripts. and then try may be it works.

Comment: same thing... there are no changes...
I just think it might be some bug when converting to apk, the url that my device search is "android_asset/www/cordova_pluging.js" but the real path is "android/asset/www/cordova_plugings.js" I don't know if phonegap do any convertions or something but it's weird...

Comment: Did you have this plugin `phonegap-mobile-accessibility` in your app?

Comment: no, should I add it?

Answer (score 0):

If any file name is not correct or any spelling mistake it will not show in browser. bcz browser is not case sensitive.. but device is case sensitive. check your file names and folder names.

If you want to test which error throwing when you install app.. Go to remote debugging.

Its like, you can see errors in browser, when you operate app in device.

Procedure for remote debugging:

Make sure your device is USB debugging,

open browser in your mubile, just minimize

connect mobile to pc using usb,

in command prompt, type "ionic run android"

Now go to PC browser, click on setting button (right corner 3 dots),

go to more tools, then developer tools, in that you can find your device name

once app fire up in your device, click on inspect in browser. then it will show error if it is there.

I hope you understand. If not plz ask.

Comment: There was no erros on that... just in installation it says: "Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/cordova_plugins.js" the project folder is android/asset/www but I don't know if phonegap convert the folder to android_asset